# SQL join tables with condition

Tags: sql, database-design, join

So I would like to join 2 tables with 1 where condition:

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT * FROM (ci_usertags) 
JOIN ci_tags ON ci_usertags.utag_tid
WHERE utag_uid = 1
```

My tables look like this:

```
ci_usertags 
  utag_id 
  utag_uid
  utag_tid

ci_tags 
  tag_id
  tag_name
```

I want to select all `tag`s for user with `ID` 1 and get the `tag name`. With this SQL I am getting duplicate results and even the `tags` which are not for the user with `ID` 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`ci_usertags`) JOIN
     `ci_tags`
     ON `ci_usertags`.`utag_tid`
WHERE `utag_uid`
```

This is sort of non-sensical SQL.  The conditions are that `utag_tid` is not 0 or NULL and `utag_uid` is not 0 or NULL.  This is because there are no conditions, so it is only looking at the value of a variable.  In some other SQL engines, this would result in errors.

I think you want something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM `ci_usertags` ut JOIN
     `ci_tags` t
     ON ut.`utag_tid` = t.tag_id
WHERE `utag_uid` = 1
```

Comment: Lol ofc. So silly of me. Made a small mistake when writing query in framework. Thanks. I will accept answer asap

Answer (score 2):

Solution with nested query as replacement for join (speed improvement)

```
Select tag_id, tag_name
FROM ci_tags
WHERE tag_id IN (Select utag_tid FROM ci_usertags WHERE utag_id = 1 GROUP BY 1)
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Answer (score 1):

replace:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`ci_usertags`) JOIN
     `ci_tags`
     ON `ci_usertags`.`utag_tid`
WHERE `utag_uid`
```

on:

```
SELECT *
FROM `ci_usertags` ut JOIN
     `ci_tags` t
     ON ut.`utag_tid` = t.tag_id
WHERE `utag_uid` = 1
```